# Going back to previous screen

Tags: android, android-activity

Let say i have  activity a,b,c,d . I can open d from any of the `Activity` . Now I want when user press back button from D it should go back to prev screen but D should be in stack so i can not call `finish()` . I tried with

intent with clear top flag or

```
  Intent i = new Intent();
   i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
   i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
   startActivity(i);
```

when i press back on D it showing **notification** when he click on **notification**   (even app is in background or foreground)it should kill D `Activity`

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) flag in the intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context /*e.g. ActivityD*/, ActivityB.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: this for b -> D na ? hw i can go d->b

Comment: so i have to make track of it from where it coming  coz i dont want every time it shld open B it can A,BorC

Comment: Perhaps you should edit the original question and explain more about what you are trying to do in your app. There might be a better way to design the navigation and avoid trying to manage the history stack with things like `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT `